# Where should I redirect hackers / hacking scripts to?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

Some hacker has been annoying me today by succesfully altering my database with a certain type of DOM injection, using automated scripts.

I fixed my website, but on top of that I want to redirect future hacking attempts to a website. I have tried to search for suggestions, but cannot find any good websites which will either:

- automatically report the hacking attempt to the authorities,
- or will frustrate the hacker/scripts

Simple example; I can block most of the SQL injections in .htaccess, and now my question is, which website do I send the traffic to?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (eval\() [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(javascript)(.*) [NC,OR]
.... etc.
RewriteRule .* https://www.nsa.gov/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Just drop the connection as every adult person would do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule .* https://www.nsa.gov/? [L,R=301]
> ```

Don't bother trying to redirect the request, just block it with a 403 Forbidden (or 404).

- No other site will want to receive these "hacker" requests.
- The "hacker" (most probably a bot) probably won't follow the redirect anyway.

In other words, to send a 403, it's simply...

```
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

`^` is more efficient than `.*` in this case, since `.*` must traverse the entire URL-path (matches everything), whereas `^` simply asserts the start-of-string (matches nothing, but successful for everything).

Or to return a 404, change `F` to `R=404`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was hoping that somewhere on the worldwide web   automated hack-script reporting website would exist. Such a site might help to give script-kids the impression that they can't get away with it. Gap in the market?

Anyway, your [R=404] suggestion in the .htaccess is a good one. The least I can do is complicate the replies to the injection scripts. Is there perhaps a even better way to confuse the scripted injection attempts?

Comment: Perhaps [R=408] or [R=410] are better alternatives instead of [F]? Since it's not really a 404 situation. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors

Comment: "automated hack-script reporting" - there would be no "one central [public] hack-script reporting website" (too many requests, too open to abuse, unreliable). There could well be smaller (private) sites that expose an API to record this information. But this would not be done with a "redirect". A redirect loses important information about the initial request (it is after all, an entirely separate request) and no guarantee that the redirect would be followed.

Comment: The "bot" is most probably looking for a specific response... perhaps a 200 OK with a certain response body. Anything other than this may just be rejected. So sending a 408, 410 or 418 probably isn't going to "confuse" the bot, it will just get rejected as "not the expected response". What might be useful is to send back as small a response as possible - so as to not waste your bandwidth. (You can't simply drop the connection / time-out the request on Apache AFAIK). See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/906027/49157) to a related question on ServerFault for some ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to a random local network address, e.g. http://168.192.1.200. On most devices that'll cause it to hang for ages before timing out, without wasting your server resources, and should hopefully slow down any scripts looking for hundreds of URLs on your website.

I don't use WordPress, and most hacker's bots are searching for URLs based on one of the main WordPress locations, so I've got this in my htaccess. If these strings are found anywhere in the requested URL it'll bounce them onto their own local network, hang, then fail...

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wp-admin [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wp-login [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wp-json [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wp-content

RewriteRule .? http://192.168.0.200 [L,R]